# Assign a value to a row from the position of a sort table

Tags: mysql, mariadb, window-functions, database-trigger, sql-view

I have a MySQL table with rows: id, score and rank. I want to make a trigger that sort the table and assign the new position to the rank value of the table, for example: id. nick. score. rank

```
John. 8. ?
Mike. 10. ?
Al. 5. ?
Terry. 12. ? SORT BY score= id nick. score. rank.
Terry. 12. 1
Mike 10. 2
John. 8. 3
Al. 5. 4
```

I know how to sort the table with the sentence `ORDER BY score DESC`, but I don't know how to assign the new position of the elements to the rank. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend storing the rank in the table itself. This is a *derived information*, that can be computed on the fly whenever needed. On the other hand, storing it incurs *maintaining it*: you will find yourself creating stored procedures for each and every DML operation (update, insert, delete).

You could create a view instead. If you are running MySQL 8.0 or MariaDB >= 10.3, you can use window functions:

```
create view myview as
select 
    id, 
    score,
    rank() over(order by score desc) rnk
from mytable
```

This gives you an always up-to-date perspective at your data, with 0 maintenance costs.

Note that `rank` is a SQL keyword, hence not a good choice for a column name - I named the column `rnk` instead.

Comment: I don't understand where is created this view, in the server where have I the table? Then can I take from the view the first ten results?

Comment: @MartíAmatVila: yes the view is created in the server. You can select from the view like you would select from another other table.